# Android: native memory lack

Tags: android, android-ndk

I have two Samsung Galaxy S2 bought together at same time, one with Android 2.3.4 and one with 4.0.3.

I java class initialize few native library (FFMPEG) and launch an AsyncTask to convert two files.

On the device with 4.0.3, I can launch two time the AsyncTask for two different conversion, and the task end successfully.

On the device with 2.3.4, the first task start fine, when I launch the second, the app restart (native crash)

I think the difference could be how the system load the native libs? probably on ICS Google fix something? what can I check?

**UPDATE**

Enabling CheckingJNI, I get this error in LogCat:

06-04 18:43:40.343: A/libc(28648): @@@ ABORTING: INVALID HEAP ADDRESS IN internal_realloc

Comment: Did you ever find what caused the `INVALID HEAP ADDRESS IN internal_realloc` error?